# R can't save to PRN.rData

Tags: r

If you try to save any dataset to "PRN.rData", you'll get an error:

```
d<- data.frame(D=NA, K=NA)
save(d, file="E:/PRN.rData")

Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'E:/PRN.rData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

What's going on? Is it just me?

Comment: That's the only software I know. So is R good for everything except for PRN?

Comment: It was a joke (a bad one).. Anyway interesting find IMO. My guess it somewhat Windows related rather R. What's your OS?

Comment: I shouldn't use Windows for PRN? PS. It's Windows

Comment: Is that a valid path for your system? Do you have rights to the `E:` unit? Excuse my ignorance, but what's PRN and why does it have a role here?

Comment: Try creating a new folder manually in Windows (not in R) and rename it `PRN`. IT won't work for some reason. It's definitely Windows related behaviour. You need to watch less PRN in R mate.

Comment: @nicola, I tried it, crashed my session... it's not a path problem

Comment: Holy f#ck. You're right. It's Windows

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/704418/windows-7-delete-folder-called-prn) seems related and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/86999/unable-to-rename-a-folder-or-a-file-as-con)

Comment: PRN is a reserved name in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It's Windows related. [You can't name a file or folder 'PRN'](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/why-cant-we-create-a-folder-with-name-or-we-can-do/dc090cee-c5c1-4cc8-8d52-01cb55d599c0?auth=1)

Comment: To complement on the reserved names: [Full list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/74496)